# Can't able to fetch facebook's user data in my android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using following code to logout from facebook..

```
public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        if (!session.isClosed()) {              
            //session.close();
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    } else {
        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        //session.close();
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

After this, I am unable to fetch user details after logging in as I am getting null GraphUser in..

```
mFacebookLogin.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {                 
                getFacebookUserInformation();
            }else {
            //handle error case      
            }
        }
    });
```

and I am getting callback in

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception      exception) {           
        Log.i("facebook", "isOpened: "+state.isOpened());
        Log.i("facebook", "isClosed: "+state.isClosed());
    }
};
```

with state as isClosed true.

So in a nutshell flow is like this..

1. open my android app
2. click on facebook login button
3. native facebook app will open and ask for user credentials.
4. enter user credentials
5. after Login native facebook app will ask for app permission to access public profile and email.
6. user authorize the app
7. call comes back to android app , first in onAcvitityResult(), then in onUserInfoFetched() after that in call(). In onUserInfoFetched GraphUser is not null and in call() state is opened.
8. Android app makes a separate request to get user details and show it on app UI.
9. Logout from android app and call facebooklogut() function. Close the android app.
10. Open the android app(its a new android app session)
11. go on screen where facebook login button is there.
12. Click on facebook login button.
13. facebook native app opens with progressdialog.
14. Since user is already signed in and already authorized the android app, call comes back to android app.
15. but this time onUserInfoFetched() has null GraphUser and call() method has closed state.
16. So I am unable to fetch user details

Comment: Please provide your log file.

Comment: This is resolved...after I started checking for Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE in onActivityResult()